# Is this an existing function?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assume I have 4 tuples of numbers. Input tuples' size is limited to 2.

$$(1,2), (5,6), (1,8), (2,7) $$

After applying a function or operations the result is

$$(1,2,8,7), (5,6)$$

What has happened is, if there is a common element between two tuples, there are `union`-ed. There result could be one or more tuple without size limitation.

Is there a name for this operation in mathematics? Or this is just a complex set operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ordering of the tuples is irrelevant, then yes, this is an important construction! Your input is the set of edges in a [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)), and your output is the partition of that graph into [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)).

Concerning the name of the function, for example, the NetworkX library literally calls it [`connected_components()`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components).

If the ordering within and among all the tuples must be observed, then I guess you have an edge-ordered directed graph, and you want an ordered partition of vertex-ordered components. Basically the same thing, but more work; and I don't know if that function has a well-known name.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. We have a *simple graph*, and we look for its *connected components*.